# Not recognized javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have to associate a listener function to a image onclick event.
This is what I've done:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
     //some instructions
  }
</script>

<!-- Some java codes -->

</head>

<body>
<div data-role = "page" data-dom-cache = "false" id = "<%= pageID %>" data-jmob-view-type = "split" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; background-color: #162828">
    <div style="margin-left: 7%; margin-right: 7%; margin-top: 7%">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; margin-bottom: 4%; justify-content: flex-end;">

            <img src = '<%=IMGHelper.includeIMG(request, response, "image_path", null) %>' onclick = 'myFunction()' style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"/>
            <span style="display:inline-block; width: 2%;"></span>
            <img src = '<%=IMGHelper.includeIMG(request, response, "image_path", null) %>' onclick = 'myFunction()' style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" />
        </div> 
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When I click on one of those image debugger shows this error: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"`. How it is possible?

Comment: what do you see if you run `window.myFunction` in the console?

Comment: Don't you have any error in your JavaScript code so that myFunction becomes not defined?

Comment: @Christiaan this jsp is only accesible from my app webView, i can not use console commands

Comment: @SergeyMell no errors. I also tried to compile the jsp and it builds.

Comment: @SamuelAdorni I tried running your code in stacksnippet by putting a `console.log` inside your function and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED (for me)]

I omitted one important particular: this jsp is at the end of jsp inclusion chain. So when I call "myFunction()" my webView searches only in the root jsp file and it doesn't find anything.

Fast (and ugly) solution: move the function to the root jsp

Best solution: there could be the way to make "internal" `<script>` visible but the first solution is enough for me.

HTH

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with the src substitutes format or any special character that is not escaped.

```
<%=IMGHelper.includeIMG(request, response, "image_path", null) %>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30kpjobw/ as it is working fine here

Answer (score -2):

Try to make the function visible in the variable scope of the **.ready()** handler..

Comment: Can you link an example or write something similar, thank you.

Comment: It's not in a ready handler in the first place. It's already in the global scope.

Comment: There OP isn't using jQuery so there isn't a `ready` function anyway.